# webview error screen showing blank page

Tags: android, html, css, networking

I'm working on setting a "no network" error page with image and text. I have created a .html file with image, text, css with dreamweaver for this. All I am getting is a blank page.

[image]

I have googled and searched stack overflow, tried placing HTML content in a bunch of places and formatting the path to it in a bunch of ways as recommended. Still getting blank white screen.

in addition: now refreshing content with no network does not show blank page and refreshing with network reconnected no longer returns to content when refresh pressed.

Comment: I know you mentioned that you changed the path but have you tried:
"file:///Network_Error/index.html"? (just the colon added cause it's missing from the image you posted)

Comment: Oh, ok!
 now system registering that I am asking it to load from a directory. It is spitting out "web page at file:///..." not found. Where is the correct place to put them for a webview? I have it in main/assets and main/assets/Network_Error and res/assets/ and res/assets/Network_Error and res/raw/Network_Error and res/raw

Comment: Ah, got it!

Its all incorrectly formatted, but it finally showed up with "file:///android_asset/index.html" with the actual folder structure main/assets/index.html(+supportfiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, got it! Its all incorrectly formatted, but it finally showed up with "file:///android_asset/index.html" with the actual folder structure main/assets/index.html(+supportfiles)

Network_Error folder made by Dreamweaver was getting in the way.

Thanks Driss